# Creating RDS cloudformation with route 53

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am having trouble with aws cloud formation. I need to create cloudformation that will install and configure RDS with RHEL and mariadb with route 53 and master user. I started first with basic config.yaml but i am getting an error with vpc, it says

> No default VPC for this user (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400;
>   Error Code: VPCIdNotSpecified; Request ID:
>   407bd74c-9b85-4cce-b5a7-b816fe7aea15)

My config.yaml is this

```
Resources:
   Ec2Instance1:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
      Properties:
           SecurityGroups:
               - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
           KeyName: adivir
           ImageId: ami-07dfba995513840b5
           AvailabilityZone: eu-central-1
           InstanceType: t2.micro
           UserData:
              Fn::Base64: !Sub |
               #!/bin/bash -xe
               yum install -y httpd
               yum install -y git
               yum install -y php php-mysql
               git clone https://github.com/demoglot/php.git /var/www/html
               systemctl restart httpd
               systemctl enable httpd
   Ec2Instance2:
      Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
      Properties:
           SecurityGroups:
               - !Ref InstanceSecurityGroup
           KeyName: adivir
           ImageId: ami-07dfba995513840b5
           AvailabilityZone: eu-central-1
           InstanceType: t2.micro
           UserData:
             Fn::Base64: !Sub |
               #!/bin/bash -xe
               yum install -y httpd
               yum install git -y
               git clone https://github.com/demoglot/php.git /var/www/html
               systemctl restart httpd
               systemctl enable httpd
   InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '2256'
          ToPort: '2256'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
   ElasticLoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
        AvailabilityZones:
             - eu-central-1
             - eu-central-1b
        Listeners:
            - InstancePort: '80'
              LoadBalancerPort: '80'
              Protocol: HTTP
        HealthCheck:
              Target: 'HTTP:80/'
              HealthyThreshold: '3'
              UnhealthyThreshold: '5'
              Interval: '30'
              Timeout: '5'
        Instances :
           - !Ref Ec2Instance1
           - !Ref Ec2Instance2
   DBSECURITYGROUP:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup'
    Properties:
          GroupDescription: Security Group for RDS private access
          DBSecurityGroupIngress:
            - CIDRIP: 0.0.0.0/0
   MyDB:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
        DBName: kk
        AllocatedStorage: '20'
        DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
        Engine: MariaDB
        EngineVersion: '10.1.31'
        MasterUsername: admin
        MasterUserPassword: admin123
        DBSecurityGroups:
            - !Ref DBSECURITYGROUP
        Tags:
           - Key: name
             Value: kk
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
```

What i need to do in order to resolve vpc error and have RDS create successfully and how and where to add route 53 creation in yaml file? Also database neds to be connected to java app athat is on other instance. What do i need to share with person making app in order for him to connect to database? Also, is it possible to have one shell script that will run cloudformations in order, create stacks and then exit so that not each team member needs to run his own cloud formation? Thank you

Comment: Hi, this seems like multiple questions. the first problem is that you're never specifying a VPC id which means the default behavior is to go to the default VPC. If theres no default this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem and why it occurs have been documented and explained in the resent AWS blog:

- [How do I resolve the CloudFormer error “No default VPC found for this user” in AWS CloudFormation?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-cloudformer-default-vpc/)

Basically, the solution is to create new default vpc.

p.s.

I also agree with @mokugo-devops. You ask too many sub-questions which limits the focus and precision of your main question and issue you have reported.

Comment: Ah sorry, i felt like asking all at once instead bumping few different posts. I got it to work, changed few settings and it worked.  also added route 53, found it in documentation.